# Remove order is unpredictable in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following delete method in an Entity Framework Code First project:

```
var selectedID = selectedGroup.ID;
var users = (from user in db.Users
               where user.Group_ID == selectedID
               select user);
db.Users.RemoveRange(users);

db.Groups.Attach(selectedGroup);
db.Groups.Remove(selectedGroup);
db.SaveChanges();
```

These are the models:

```
 public class Group
  {
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid Branch { get; set; }

  }

  public class User
  {
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid Group_ID { get; set; }

  }
```

When `db.SaveChanges()` is called, I get an exception:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "FK_Users_Groups". The conflict occurred in database "UserDB", table
>   "dbo.Users", column 'Group_ID'. The statement has been terminated.

It seems that the Remove methods are called in a reverse (random) order. If I add *another* `db.SaveChanges()` after `RemoveRange()`, it (obviously) works okay.

How can I force the order of remove?

Comment: @Kaf Yes, that is why I delete the users first then the group. EF executes it reversely.

Comment: "If I add another db.SaveChanges() after RemoveRange(), it (obviously) works okay." There's your solution - what's wrong with that?

Comment: he may want to somehow keep using just 1 `SaveChanges`. Well I think it's better to stick with `delete on cascade` which should prevent this issue from occuring.

Comment: @DStanley If I use 2 SaveChanges that means 2 _round-trip_ to SQL server. Would you consider it more performance-effective than using only 1?

Comment: do you have any reason to disable `on delete cascade`?

Comment: @Hopeless Not really, I just don't know how to apply it for those models. It would require a ForeignKey attribute, a list of the dependent and so on. It would require a lot of extra objects.

Comment: I couldn't find out why the order was so unpredictable so I ended up using cascade delete. I leave the question open should anyone come up with a solution later.

Answer (score 4):

You need to teach EF the table relationships. It will then automatically order the DML operations for you. Declare the relationships in your model. For example, the user class should have a group property.

These properties are very useful in queries as well. Not sure how you made due without them. Writing joins manually is tedious.

Comment: What do you do if you do not want to use navigation properties and you are mapping with data attributes? We stopped using navigation properties completely because there are far too many hidden performance issues and you never know when a call on such a property is either expensive or even may result in an Exception.

Comment: @OliverSchimmer I don't think you have an option without making these relationships known to EF. Maybe make these properties `private`? Not sure if EF can handle that. Let me know what you find.

Comment: @OliverSchimmer maybe some advice from my own experience can help you: I got into the habit of checking each EF query and each type of HTTP request with SQL Profiler to make sure that the queries are as expected. There are JavaScript solutions for this as well. Maybe you *can* use navigation properties if you improve your development process a bit. These properties can be very useful. I mainly use them inside of queries, not for loading data. Much better than joining manually.

Comment: I don't think the development process is the issue here, using Navigation properties or not is a design decision. They are problematic if you want to separate your logic and model layer from your DAL. For example you cannot know in higher layers if a navigation property is already initialized or not. This is important when you cannot expect the context to be open all the time - this may work for smaller web applications, but when you have to have parallel DB queries on multiple contexts, you should work with detached entities.